# Ruby on Rails - How to recall a method from a closed do block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, erb

I've got this code in my matches index:

```
<table>
<% @matches.each do |match| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= match.team_a %></td>
    <td><%= match.team_b %></td>
    <td><%= match.score_a %> - <%= match.score_b %></td>
    <td><%= match.field %></td>
    <%= render "shared/asterisk_message", :target => [match.team_b, match.team_a] %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I want to move the rendered asterisk_message **outside** the table, but this would mean to put it after the `<% end %>`, which obviously gives me this error:

> undefined local variable or method `match' for #<#:0xb6da40d8>

How can I work it out?

Comment: But... `match` doesn't make any sense outside the context of the table? Do you want there to be more than one `shared/asterisk_message` also?

Comment: again iterate out side table and render

Comment: @Xymostech I didn't want to render another `shared/asterisk_message`, I wanted to move the one I've already got **outside** the table. Otherwise, `match` wouldn't make any sense outside the `do` block (unless, as @SaurabhJain and  @Amar suggested, we iterate the `do` block another time outside the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<table>
    <% @matches.each do |match| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= match.team_a %></td>
        <td><%= match.team_b %></td>
        <td><%= match.score_a %> - <%= match.score_b %></td>
        <td><%= match.field %></td>
        <%= render "shared/asterisk_message", :target => [match.team_b, match.team_a] %>
    <% end %>
    </table>

<% @matches.each do |match| %>
<%= render "shared/asterisk_message", :target => [match.team_b, match.team_a] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to know (and what I wanted to learn too).